# issue having logstash read a file and output to both stdout and another file

Tags: logstash

I have a project I am working on and wanted to try to hook it up to the ELK stack beginning with logstash. Essentially I have python writing this to a file named stockLog:

```
{'price': 30.98, 'timestamp': '2015-08-03 09:51:54', 'symbol':'FORTY',
  'ceiling': Decimal('31.21'), 'floor': Decimal('30.68')}
```

I have logstash installed and (ideally) ready to run. My logstash.conf file looks like this:

```
input {
    file { path => "/home/test001/stockLog"
    start_position => beginning }
    }
output {
    stdout {}
        file {
              path => "/home/test001/testlog"
             }
    }
```

My goal is to actually be able to see how logstash is going to read the python dictionary before I install Elasticsearch and start keeping data. Essentially even though logstash has a lot of formatting options I would like to just have my python script do the lifting and put it in a format that is easiest to work with downstream.

My problem is that no matter what I change in the logstash.conf file I can't get anything to print to my terminal showing what logstash is doing. I get no errors but when I execute this command:

```
test001@test001:~$ sudo /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /opt/logstash/logstash.conf
```

I get a message saying logstash has started correctly and the options of typing into my terminal but no stdout showing what it did if anything with the dictionary in my stockLog file.

So far I have tried "" around the file name and not. I have added the file output which you can see above to see if it actually writes anything to that file even though I don't see output on my terminal (it does not) and I have tried using the `codec => rubydebug` to see if logstash just needed an idea of the format I wanted to see. Nothing shows me any sign that logstash is doing anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I there is more information needed by all means let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: start_position, as documented, is only for the first time a file is seen, and may not be what you're expecting.  Make sure that's not what's confusing the situation.

Comment: Have you tried cranking up debugging in logstash?

Comment: I haven't tried debug I will have to learn how it works when I get home and give it a whirl. I took out the start_position statement entirely just to try and reduce the possible issues. I also decided to just go ahead and turn on elasticsearch and kibana to see if I got anything.

Comment: What I found is that after running my python script which opens the file, inserts the dictionary, and closes the file I get no data into logstash. However, after I manually open the file and save it I immediately see the information both get output on my terminal and go to elasticsearch. I think my problem might have to do with the way python is opening and closing the script but am still investigating. Please let me know if that tips any of you off as to the problem!

Comment: logstash is built to read from the end of the file.  Opening it and overwriting the contents is not the correct usage pattern; appending is.  The start position is only used when the file is first seen.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the answer turned out to be three steps.

1. Like mentioned above I needed to stop overwriting the file and just append to it instead.
2. I used the json filter to have the data easily broken down the way I wanted to see it. Once converted into json with json.dumps in python the logstash json filter handled the data easily.
3. I realized that it is pointless to try and see what logstash is going to do prior to putting it into elasticsearch because it is extremely easy to remove the information if it isn't shaped right (I am to indoctrinated by permanent indexes in splunk sorry guys).